# Return mono object from subscribe in restcontroller

Tags: spring, redis, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

I have the following rest controller which reads data from redis and then needs to return some response

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class ViewController {
@GetMapping(value = "/{channelId}/**")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<ViewResponse>> viewObject(@PathVariable(value = "channelId") String channelId) {

    redisController.getChannelData(channelInfoset, channelId).subscribe(response -> {
        if (response != null)
            return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<ViewResponse>(new ViewResponse("val", "1", false), HttpStatus.OK));
        else return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<ViewResponse>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    });

}}
```

This is the redis function to get data

```
public Mono<Object> getChannelData(String key, String value) {
    return reactiveStringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().get(key,value);
}
```

How can I return the `ViewResponse` object after subscribe?

Comment: Use `map` instead of `subscribe` and a `defaultIfEmtpy`.

Comment: @M.Deinum using `map` doesn't gets invoked until I use `subscribe` on it. Using subscribe gives the `Disposable` object

Comment: You don't need to subscribe. The mono that gets returned will be subscribed to by your client. I also wonder shouldn't the return type be `Mono<ResponseEntity<ViewResponse>>` instead of what you have now?

Comment: as pointed out, dont call `subscribe` the calling client is the subscriber.... return the mono to the client, this is basic reactive programming, read the getting started in the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

Comments from `M. Deinum` helped me out and was to resolve with

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class ViewController {
@GetMapping(value = "/{channelId}/**")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<ViewResponse>> viewObject(@PathVariable(value = "channelId") String channelId) {

return redisController.getChannelData(channelInfoset, channelId).map(response -> {
    if (response != null)
        return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<ViewResponse>(new ViewResponse("val", "1", false), HttpStatus.OK));
    else return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<ViewResponse>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
});

}}
```